# Local Folder Redirection to Mapped Network Drive Batch File

Tags: batch-file, redirect, directory

Im attempting to automate our user configuration which we do locally per user which is why I am doing it through a batch file. As a part of this I need to redirect their Documents folder to what is mapped as their U Drive. If a My Documents Folder is present in their U Drive I need it to go there, if not I need it to be mapped to the root of their U Drive.

The code below is what I currently have, but it always defaults to the Else condition even when I have the folder I am check for.

If anyone could help, please do.

```
@echo off 
cd\ & cls
set UDRIVE="u:\My Documents\"
If exist %udrive% (set newDocuments=%udrive%) Else (set newDocuments=U:\)

set registryPath1="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
set registryPath2="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

>null reg add %registryPath1% /v "Personal" /t REG_SZ /d %newDocuments% /f
>null reg add %registryPath2% /v "Personal" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %newDocuments% /f
>null reg add %registryPath2% /v "{F42EE2D3-909F-4907-8871-4C22FC0BF756}" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %newDocuments% /f
echo Redirection completed.



%echo%
Pause
%echo%
```

Comment: Use `IF exist "%udrive%\" (GOTO  :FolderRedirect)  ELSE  GOTO :FolderRedirect2`. Read `if /?` for basic explanation.

Comment: Its still defaulting to the Else condition. No matter if the target folder exist its still defaulting to the Else condition.

Comment: Insert `goto :somewhere` just before the `:FolderRedirect2` label.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. Ive gotten it to recognize both arguments now, but when it tries to write to the registry the script stalls out and does nothing. Ive edited my original post to reflect my new code. It runs fine when it defaults to the Else argument, but stalls when running the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign quotes to your variables (see [this Squashman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810044/win-batch-if-exist-date-within-filename-search-not-working#comment80569987_46810044)): *Best practice is to assign your variables like this: `set "varname=varvalue"`. This helps preserve special characters and spaces but does not assign quotes to your variable*. Then, refer to them using double quotes explicitly like `"%varname%"`

Above rule applied to your code snippet as follows:

```
@echo off 
cd\ & cls
set "UDRIVE=u:\My Documents\"
If exist "%udrive%" (set "newDocuments=%udrive%") Else (set "newDocuments=U:\")

set "registryPath1=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
set "registryPath2=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

>null reg add "%registryPath1%" /v "Personal" /t REG_SZ /d "%newDocuments%\" /f
>null reg add "%registryPath2%" /v "Personal" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%newDocuments%\" /f
>null reg add "%registryPath2%" /v "{F42EE2D3-909F-4907-8871-4C22FC0BF756}" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%newDocuments%\" /f
echo Redirection completed.
```

Please note: **Backslash characters**

> The `REG` command will interpret `\` as an escape for the character that
>   immediately follows it. To include a quote mark (`"`) in the data,
>   prefix it with the escape character e.g. Here is `\"` a quote.
>   This can cause problems with quoted directory paths because `\"` at
>   the end of the line will be escaped. 
>  To save a directory path
>   with a trailing backslash (`\`) requires adding a second backslash to
>   'escape' the escape so for example instead of "C:\My Docs\" use "C:\My
>   Docs\".

Comment: Alright im right there with you, but its still hanging when it tries to redirect it to U:\My Documents\  Im wondering if I need to delete the keys before adding them?? To be honest im all out of ideas.

Comment: If I take the space out of the UDRIVE path it works just fine everything else the same. How can I get it to work with the space?

Comment: Please see updated answer (note: Backslash characters). Check `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"` (and `User Shell Folders` as well).

Comment: Thank you. Seriously saved me from a major headache.