# Win Batch - IF EXIST %date% within filename search - not working

Tags: batch-file

I've this little script that is not working:

```
set actdate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
set source="\\somewhere\APPL\Logs"
set target="C:\TEMP\nebu_%actdate%.log"
echo %actdate%
if exist "%source%\*%actdate%*.txt" (
    echo vorhanden
    echo %source%\*%actdate%*.txt
) else (
    echo Nicht vorhanden
)
```

When I ran the script I get following output:

```
20171018
vorhanden
"\\somewhere\APPL\Logs"\*20171018*.txt
Nicht vorhanden
```

Now the thing is that there is actually no file with `*20171018*.txt` in source:

```
NeBuExport.20171017.102600.txt
NeBuExport.20171016.080552.txt
NeBuExport.20171013.093638.txt
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: well, according to your output, both `if exist` code AND `else` code gets executed. That's not possible with the code you show. Recheck your code.

Comment: Your code ran as expected for me, and produced results as I would expect - quite different from your report. I'm intrigued by your statement "no file with *20171018Ü*.txt in source:" - the `Ü` leads me to suspect that you are not saving this batch as ANSI-encoded but as unicode. Save it as ANSI and see whether that fixes it.

Comment: Ignore the "Ü", that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Why is it executing both echo statements? The first "exist" query is not true, so why is it not only executing the true phase but also the "else" one?

Comment: I have converted it with Ultra Edit to ANSI, makes no difference. I'm working on the server with notepad only, to edit this cmd file.

Comment: Don't assign quotes to your variables. Best practice is to assign your variables like this: `set "source=\\somewhere\APPL\Logs"`.  This helps preserve special characters and spaces but does not assign quotes to your variable. That won't fix your magical output though.  Pretty sure you are not showing us something.

Comment: How is the batch script called?

Comment: it's called: command.cmd

Comment: I don't understand why someone would vote to close this question as "not being about programming". Of course this question is about batch programming. The only flaw in the question is the code was unintentionally modified in a way that causes the problem to be not reproducible.

Comment: @Stephan - The problem is the actual path has spaces within, coupled with the extra set of quotes in the assignment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815790/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

Squashman hit the nail on the head with his comment - Your unexpected behavior is the result of quotes in your assignment, coupled with space(s) within your source path. Actually, the problem could arise if your path contains any token delimiter like `=`, `,`, `;`, or `<space>`

Suppose your source assignment is `set source="\\some path\APPL\Logs"`. The value of source is `"\\some path\APPL\Logs"`, including the quotes.

Then your IF statement expands to:

```
if exist ""\\some path\APPL\Logs"\*20171018*.txt" (
```

Because of the doubled quotes, the space is not quoted, so what is intended to be a single token is treated as two tokens.

IF tests if `""\\some` exists, and if it does, then it tries to execute the following bogus command:

```
path\APPL\Logs"\*20171018*.txt"
```

The `(` is treated as an argument to the bogus command, not as the beginning of a code block.

Of course `""\\some` does not exist, so the bogus command is not executed and you don't receive any error message.

It should now be obvious why all three ECHO statements execute.

The last "mystery" is why the `) else (` and `)` statements do not produce any error. This is a result of the fact that `)` effectively functions as a `REM` if there is not any active parenthetical code block to close. All text after the `)` is ignored, just like a remark.

Your code should operate as intended if you subtly change the definition of your source as Squashman suggested:

```
set "source=\\some path\APPL\Logs"
```

Now your value becomes `\\some path\APPL\Logs`, without quotes, and everything works :-)

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked:

```
set "actdate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%"
set "source=\\somewhere\APPL\Nebu Agent\Logs"
set "target=C:\TEMP\nebu_%actdate%.log"

if exist "%source%\*%actdate%*.txt" (
    echo "vorhanden"
) else (
    echo "Nicht vorhanden"
)
```

It needed to have quotes in if statement as well
Thanks to all :)